# Unknown id: jenkins

Tags: unix, jenkins

`su -s /bin/bash jenkins` and I get back    `Unknown id: jenkins`

I need to install zip for the jenkins user, I did it for root but it isn't able to find it whenever jenkins runs. For some reason I am unable to su jenkins, and it is not in the

```
/etc/passwords file
```

but a  `echo $USER` from jenkins shows the user to be:  `jenkins`

Comment: If you really want someone to answer your question, you have to provide more details: What is your operating system? How did you install Jenkins? How do you start Jenkins? If you go to $JENKINS_URL/systemInfo and scroll down to the line that says user.name, what is the user it claims to be running as?

Comment: Replace $JENKINS_URL with the address of your Jenkins.